# Javascript,Ajax Internal Server Error 500 Post method during deleting process

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

```js
function sil(r, slug) {
  var sira = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  swal({
    title: 'Silmek İstedinize Emin Misiniz ?',
    text: 'Sildiğinizde Geri Dönüşümü Olmayacaktır!',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: 'iptal',
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Evet, Sil!'

  }).then(function() {
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: '',
      data: {
        'slug': slug,
        '_token': CSRF_TOKEN
      },
      beforeSubmit: function() {
        swal({
          title: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>',
          text: 'Yükleniyor Lütfen Bekleyiniz..',
          showConfirmButton: false,


        })
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.durum == 'success') {
          document.getElementById("datatable-buttons").deleteRows(sira);
        }
        swal(
          response.baslik,
          response.icerik,
          response.durum

        );
      }
    })
  })
```

Sil is a function for deleting.I am using laravel.I want to delete with ajax and js but I have a problem.When I want to delete,I encounter internal server 500 error.
[Error is appearing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyAFU.png)

Comment: As it says, its a server error, nothing to do with JS code.

Comment: Can you post the php error? It should be in your Laravel error log.

Comment: Please can you show what the response is from your network tab?

Comment: I want to post there but cannot post internal server error exist.This code works another computer just I copy and paste.It can not work but this script code block works my friends computers we didnt understand why cant work in my computer in my project.

Comment: I aldready fixed thanks

Answer (score 0):

why your url in post data is empty

```
       url = http://localhost/index.php //like this
       $.ajax({
  type: "Post",
  url:url,   //where url is declared
  data: {
    'slug': slug,
    '_token': CSRF_TOKEN
  },
```